# Upload image and save to my folder in php

Tags: php, html, file-upload

I have been trying to utilize the move_uploaded_file function in PHP however, nothing is working, I want the user to be able to upload a file, then the file is saved into my folder (p), below is my code, any help would be great.

index.php:

```
<html>
        <head>
                <title>test</title>
        </head>
<body bgcolor="black">
        <font color="white">
<form action="upload.php" method="post">
        <input type="file" name="file" id="file">
        <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

upload.php:

```
<html>
<head>
        <title>Helo World</title>
</head>
<body bgcolor="black">
<font color="white">
<?php
        move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], 'p/file.jpg');
?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You did not put attributes
 `<form action="upload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">`

Please read that pages https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_file_upload.asp

Comment: You must to put attribute to forum tag `enctype="multipart/form-data"`

Comment: Thank you, this worked, how would I go about saving the files' uploaded name as the same when it saves in my folder?

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you need to set the form to accept uploaded file. So the form needs to have enctype="multipart/form-data" like the code below:

```
<html>
        <head>
                <title>test</title>
        </head>
<body bgcolor="black">
        <font color="white">
<form action="upload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <input type="file" name="file" id="file">
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" name="submit">
</form>
```

The the php would be something like:

```
<?php


    $targetFile = 'uploads/' . basename($_FILES["file"]["name"]);

    if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], $targetFile)) {
      //file was successfully uploaded
    }



?>
```

Comment: `if(isset($_POST["submit"])` would fail them, as it would generate a parse error. Then:  `$_FILES["fileToUpload"]` being the wrong array.